# Transaction with oracle procedures

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures, transactions

I tried rollback the transaction after calling the stored procedure in the transaction, but all the changes in the database are still active.

Code:

```
using (DbContext context = new DbContext("name=data"))
      {
      try
        {
             using (DbContextTransaction transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {

                var mID = _id ?
                     new ObjectParameter("mID", _id) :
                     new ObjectParameter("mID", typeof(int));
    
                ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("MY_PROCEDURE", mID,);
                       
               // some condition of with ret.Value
              transaction.Rollback();
```

Procedure has not own transaction. DB autocommit is off.

I using .NET framework version 4.5.0. (Where is not TransactionScope)

Changes using a using and try block did not change behavior.

I also tried isolationLevel but no change.

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [MRE] that includes example code for the `MY_PROCEDURE` stored procedure that you are calling.

Answer (score 0):

If the stored procedure `MY_PROCEDURE` includes a `COMMIT` statement at the end of the procedure then when you try to `ROLLBACK` the transaction it will `ROLLBACK` to the last `COMMIT` and since you have explicitly told it to `COMMIT` in the procedure then there will be no subsequent changes to `ROLLBACK`.

If this is the case, your code is working as designed but the design does not match your intentions; to fix it, you need to remove the `COMMIT` statement from the procedure and then when you `ROLLBACK` the transaction it will `ROLLBACK` to the start of the transaction.

*(Note: DDL statements will implicitly `COMMIT` before and after each DDL statement; if your procedure runs and includes DDL statements then you will **NEVER** be able to `ROLLBACK` the transaction to before those statements.)*

---

In general, you should not use a `COMMIT` statement in procedures as it prevents you from controlling the transaction outside the procedure (as you have found) and means you cannot call multiple procedures in the same transaction and choose to `ROLLBACK` them all if one of the later ones fails.

*(Note: The exception to this is autonomous transactions where you (almost) always do want to `COMMIT` inside the procedure as they are executed outside of the transaction's session so the normal transaction control of the session will not affect their behaviour.)*

Comment: In procedure i do not use transaction, commit or rollback

Comment: @MatejB If the procedure contains DDL statements then they will implicitly `COMMIT` before and after each DDL statement.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any option that would allow me to call a transaction on the server, call procedure and make rollback?

Comment: @MatejB Yes, don't `COMMIT` or use DDL statements in the procedure (which would implicitly `COMMIT`) and then you can use transaction controls to `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` outside the procedure. You haven't shared the code for the procedure so its not possible to comment beyond generic advice.